# Multiple spinners in an activity - can it be refactored to make it generated dynamically?

Tags: android, view, spinner

I need to put multiple spinners into my activity. Number of them would be defined dynamically, it would be 2-7 items.

At the moment I have something like:

```
-- clip:

Spinner spinnerOne = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBrowse);
spinnerOne.setAdapter(new Adapter(Browse.this, R.layout.browse_spinner_rows, picsIds)); 
spinnerOne.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Spinner spinnerTwo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBrowse);
spinnerTwo.setAdapter(new Adapter(Browse.this, R.layout.browse_spinner_rows, picsIds)); 
spinnerTwo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

-- clap.
```

Contents of these spinners is the same, they only vary by names. Is it somehow possible to iterate by these names, like putting names into array { "SpinnerOne", "SpinnerTwo", "SpinnerThree", ... } and just generate number of needed spinner items in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure define a container on your layout and then add spinners dinamically

```
int numOfSpinners;
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
for(int i=0;i<numOfSpinners;i++)
{
   Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
   spinner.setAdapter(new Adapter(Browse.this, R.layout.browse_spinner_rows, getPicsIds(i)));
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   container.addView(spinner);
}
```

where getPicsIds() fetches the right items for each iteration

Comment: Which imports for Browse and Adapter?